# Which compound reacts most slowly?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm trying to figure out why the answer is C. Can anyone explain to me why that is the answer?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What do you already know? I'm closing this by our homework policy (note: it applies to homework-like questions too), but if you can edit that in I'll be happy to reopen it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Nitration is a general class of chemical process for the introduction of a nitro  group into an organic chemical compound.

For introduction of Nitro group, the compound must have either partial charge or proper charge (ions) or must form a radical to form the bond between Nitro group and compund. Compound III (`option C`) is more stable and ease of charge generation or free radical generation will be less due to less difference in electronegavities of atoms.
     Due to less electronegativity difference, the shared pair of electron contributes equally to the electron density of both atoms. If electronegativity difference is higher, ease of Charge generation is higher, eg. $\ce{HCL}$ (both have Partial charges, $H^{\delta+}$ & $Cl^{\delta-}$).

This is the only reason for which the reaction will be slowest for compound C.

Comment: Please use backticks only  for code.

Answer (score 5):

Electrophilic aromatic substitution, of which nitration is one specific example, is often a kinetically controlled process, i.e., the distribution of products is determined by the energies of the transition states and intermediates of the respective reaction pathways available. Under conditions where thermodynamic equilibrium cannot be established, the predominant product will be the one with the lowest activation energy for the rate-determining step, and more stable transition states and intermediates imply lower energy of activation. This is also the product that forms most rapidly.

(Incidentally, even under thermodynamic conditions where equilibrium can be established, it's frequently the case that the major pathway will involve the initial kinetic product in equilibrium with the thermodynamic product. If I remember correctly, this is the case with, e.g., the isomerization that occurs with certain Friedel-Crafts polyalkylations.)

Given that, in order to answer your question, you need to examine the transition states of the nitration process for each of your reactants. If you consider the mechanism shown on the [Wikipedia page for electrophilic aromatic substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophilic_aromatic_substitution#Ortho.2Fpara_directors), you'll see that the cationic intermediate of the reaction is additionally stabilized when electron-donating groups are present. In your specific question, molecules I and II are both very strongly electron-donating by means of $\pi$-conjugation, which is nicely illustrated by the resonance structures one could draw for those molecules. Molecule IV is stabilized by a similar effect, although it's slightly less efficient due to the lone pair on the nitrogen also being conjugated to the electron-withdrawing carbonyl group. Molecule V is very weakly donating, but by different means. In the case of that molecule, it donates electrons by induction, and by hyperconjugation of the vacant $p$ orbital with a $\sigma$ carbon-hydrogen bond. Because the energies of $p$ orbitals and bonding $\sigma$ molecular orbitals are vastly different, and because the orbital overlap is incomplete and sensitive to conformation, the stabilization provided by the methyl substituent is comparatively minute.

As an aside, I recently became aware of another, somewhat orthogonal explanation for the reactivity of substituted aromatics, namely the frontier orbital theory approach. Fleming, in his excellent book on molecular orbital theory, explains (by analogy with the benzyl anion) that conjugation of the benzene ring with an electron-donating substituent disrupts the normal degeneracy of the $\psi_2$ and $\psi_3$ molecular orbitals, and yields a non-bonding HOMO with nodes at alternating atoms. The locations of those nodes results in relatively large coefficients on the atoms in the ortho and para positions, and very low (idealized to zero, but experimentally, of course, non-zero) coefficients on the atoms in the meta positions. I suppose this can serve as a complementary theoretical justification for the observed kinetics and perhaps regioselectivity of these types of reactions.